# unable to use imageview

Tags: c#, uiimageview, uiimage, xamarin.ios

I have a very simple monotouch applicaiton where I am trying to reference image in an uiimageview but I am not successful. Following is the listing of code and the error I keep getting. Please help. I don't know what am I doing wrong.I have double checked that GoldenGate.jpg is part of my project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace helloworld10
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args);
        }
    }

    // The name AppDelegate is referenced in the MainWindow.xib file.
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // If you have defined a view, add it here:
            // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);

            UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("GoldenGate.jpg");
            UIImageView imageview = new UIImageView(image);

            Console.WriteLine ("hello world");

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();



            return true;
        }

        // This method is required in iPhoneOS 3.0
        public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error. Please help me

```
Error connecting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:10001)

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: image
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImageView..ctor (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage image) [0x00064] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone-3/monotouch/UIKit/UIImageView.g.cs:106 
  at helloworld10.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0000b] in /Users/zulfiqarsyed/Projects/helloworld10/helloworld10/Main.cs:28 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone-3/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone-3/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:31 
  at helloworld10.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/zulfiqarsyed/Projects/helloworld10/helloworld10/Main.cs:14
```

Comment: Loos like your `UIImage image` is null.. have you checked that `UIImage.FromFile("GoldenGate.jpg")` has even returned an Image? or Null

Comment: Check Geoff Norton's answer. When you try to create a UIImage object from a file, if the file is not found, the object returns null, it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: UIImage.FromFile("GoldenGate.jpg") returns null but I do not know why its returning NULL. The jpg file is part of my project.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to bee a bug. The image must be placed in a folder, eg `@"Images/GoldenGate.jpg"` (and Build Action set to `"Content"`)

Comment: If this was a bug it doesn't seem to exist anymore as images can be placed in any folder you create with a ref to "FolderName/FileName.xxx"

Answer (score 2):

Is the file in your project called "GoldenGate.jpg" ?  Remeber that iOS devices are case sensitive, while the emulator is only case-aware.  Have you also marked the file as content in your project?

Comment: Right clicking on it does not do any thing. If I keep clicking, it opens it up as a file with strange letters. I do not get any menu or nothing changes when I right click with the mouse.

Comment: I finally fixed the right click problem. Chose mouse from system prefrences and then chose right click as secondary button. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem as well. The error occurs when it can't find the image in question. This happens when **A)** something is spelled wrong, such as the image name (it's case sensitive), or the path is wrong and **B)** the file is not marked as "Content".

So everyone else already mentioned marking it as Content I'll just elaborate on file location.  You can store it on the root or better to create a folder and call it anything you like. Then reference the image as

﻿var image = UIImage.FromBundle ("FolderName/GoldenGate.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  What fixed it for me was that my image was in Resources/Image.png.  Once I changed this to Images/Image.png it worked.  The folder seems to have to be called "Images".